# HTML5 Video Tag on iPhone not always working in iframe

Tags: iphone, html, video, iframe, html5-video

We have a page with an iframe, inside which we have an HTML5 video tag. On the iPhone, we're having a problem where it seems the video tag is not always recognized. When this happens, it doesn't get the poster frame or render a play button when it's ready. This is never a problem when the page is reloaded, but always happens when the page is visited by pressing the URL bar and pressing "Go" or by visiting the page from another page on the site.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong here? My guess is that it's due to caching, and the Mobile Safari browser isn't inspecting the tags inside of the iframe under certain circumstances. Would there be any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by moving the loading of all of our Javascript files to the end of the page.